# Minimum date for WDDX

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9, wddx

I recently had a User enter a data of 6/13/204. SQL Server 2008 happily stored the date. The date was later retrieved and serialized to WDDX. It was encoded as

```
<field name='BASECYCLEDATE'><dateTime>204-6-13T0:0:0-8:0</dateTime></field>
```

Later when I deserialized it, I get

```
 WDDX packet parse error at line 1, column 8772.. 

 Invalid date string 204-6-13T0:0:0-8:0.
```

...

```
614 :   </cfscript>
615 :   
616 :   <cfwddx action = "wddx2cfml" input = "#qryLabel.Config#" output = "stDat">
```

My question is, what is the minimum date to deserialize dates in WDDX?

Comment: That encoded string is wrong. AFAIK, it should be in [ISO8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Years) format, meaning a four digit year. A cursory test suggests `cfwddx` rejects any non-four digit years ie year < 1000 or > 9999.

Comment: Have you closed that particular barn door now that a horse has escaped?

Comment: Why are you even using WDDX?

Comment: I have to maintain a really old webservice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit:**

To answer your original question, that encoded string is wrong. The serialized dates should be in [ISO8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Years) format, meaning they should have four digit years. A cursory test suggests `cfwddx` rejects any non-four digit years ie years < 1000 or > 9999.

> SQL Server stores the date as 0204.

No, sql server does not store dates as formatted strings. Internally, they are stored as numbers. Ignoring validation for a moment, the cause is strictly on the CF side. When serializing that date into a wddx string, CF fails to generate the leading zero required by ISO8601. So the resulting string `204-6-13T0:0:0-8:0` is malformed and that is why the deserialization fails. That said, since that date range is not valid for your application, you should probably add some validation to reject invalid values like that one.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server stores the date as 0204. Apparently ColdFusion converts 0204 into 204. If users start doing this often, I will add an additional check to the data coming in. If necessary, I will

```
 <cfif year(basecyledate) LT 1000>
     ...
 </cfif>
```

Comment: *stores the date as 0204* No, sql server does not store dates as formatted strings. Internally, they are stored as numbers. Ignoring validation for a moment, the cause is strictly on the CF side. When serializing that date into a wddx string, CF fails to generate the leading zero required by [ISO8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Years). So the resulting string is malformed and that is why the deserialization fails. *RE: If necessary, I will* Well since that date range is not valid for your application, you should probably do that anyway.

Comment: I would like to use your comment as the answer as it is more complete and correct than my own